# Formatting NSDate into particular styles for both year, month, day, and hour, minute, seconds

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I basically need to get current date and time separately, formatted as:

```
2009-04-26 
11:06:54
```

The code below, from another question on the same topic, generates

```
now:        |2009-06-01 23:18:23 +0100| 
dateString: |Jun 01, 2009 23:18| 
parsed:     |2009-06-01 23:18:00 +0100|
```

This is almost what I'm looking for, but I want to separate the day and time.

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];

NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:now];

NSDateFormatter *inFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];

NSDate *parsed = [inFormat dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"\n"
"now:        |%@| \n"
"dateString: |%@| \n"
"parsed:     |%@|", now, dateString, parsed);
```

Comment: In a case like this where you've taken the time to write out the code you ended up using to solve the problem I would probably stick it (in this case everything below edit2) in an answer rather than an edit to your post. Not a big thing either way, but it makes it a bit easier to find/see that it's a solution to the question.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

iPhone format strings are in [Unicode format](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).  Behind the link is a table explaining what all the letters above mean so you can build your own.

And of course don't forget to release your date formatters when you're done with them. The above code leaks `format`, `now`, and `inFormat`.

Comment: It leaks even with ARC activated?

Comment: The above won't have any leaks under ARC (of course ARC wasn't available in 2009 when we were having this discussion).

Answer (score 194):

this is what i used:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now];

NSLog(@"\n"
      "theDate: |%@| \n"
      "theTime: |%@| \n"
      , theDate, theTime);

[dateFormat release];
[timeFormat release];
[now release];
```

Answer (score 12):

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateformat setDateFormat:@"Your Date Format"];
```

set the format to return is....

`yyyy-MM-dd` return `2015-12-17` date

`yyyy-MMM-dd`  return `2015-Dec-17` date

`yy-MM-dd` return `15-12-17` date

`dd-MM-yy`  return `17-12-15` date

`dd-MM-yyyy`  return `17-12-2015` date

`yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss`  return `2015-Dec-17 08:07:13` date and time

`yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm`  return `2015-Dec-17 08:07` date and time

For more Details Data and Time Format for [Click Now.](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Thank you.....

Comment: Please provide additional description along with the code sample.

Comment: I have this date '2018-06-08T07:30:05.391Z' i have tried 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000Z' but getting nil value.

Answer (score 11):

you can use this method  just  pass your date to it

```
-(NSString *)getDateFromString:(NSString *)string
{

    NSString * dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",string];

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"your current date format"];
    NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"your desired format"];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];

    NSLog(@"%@", stringFromDate);
    return stringFromDate;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

nothing new but still want to share my method:

```
+(NSString*) getDateStringFromSrcFormat:(NSString *) srcFormat destFormat:(NSString *)
destFormat scrString:(NSString *) srcString
{
    NSString *dateString = srcString;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:srcFormat];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    // Convert date object into desired format
    //[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:destFormat];
    NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return newDateString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**For swift**

```
var dateString:String = "2014-05-20";
var dateFmt = NSDateFormatter()
// the format you want
dateFmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
var date1:NSDate = dateFmt.dateFromString(dateString)!;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 3

```
extension Date {
    
    func toString(template: String) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: template, options: 0, locale: NSLocale.current)
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
    
}
```

### Usage

```
let now = Date()
let nowStr0 = now.toString(template: "EEEEdMMM") // Tuesday, May 9
let nowStr1 = now.toString(template: "yyyy-MM-dd") // 2017-05-09
let nowStr2 = now.toString(template: "HH:mm:ss") // 17:47:09
```

Play with template to match your needs. Examples and doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to help you build the template you need.

#### Note

You may want to cache your `DateFormatter` if you plan to use it in `TableView` for instance.
To give an idea, looping over 1000 dates took me **0.5 sec** using the above `toString(template: String)` function, compared to **0.05 sec** using `myFormatter.string(from: Date)`.

Comment: To make that note stronger (because it's very important) you may refactor your function to take an optional parameter with a default value of the new instance. I don't know why you got downvoted, so I'm upvoting it.

Answer (score -5):

```
NSDate *date         = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]
NSString *dateString  = [df stringFromDate:date];
[df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *hoursString = [df stringFromDate:date];
```

Thats it, you got it all you want.