# DatePicker iPhone get only date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datepicker

How can I get only the date from a DatePicker component on iPhone?  (better with a specific format).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe that your answer can be found in this previous question: [Formatting NSDate into particular styles for both year, month, day, and hour, minute, seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936969/nsdate-and-nsdateformatter-short-format-date-and-time-in-iphone-sdk)

Just take the date you get back from the datePicker and get just the day using NSDateFormatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:pickerDate];
[dateFormat release];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```

From the documentation:

> The exact order of these items depends on the locale setting.

Answer (score 1):

In your question you mention you want it from DatePicker component!

Anyways.. see [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)