# NSDateFormatter Adding 11 Extra Minutes when formatting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I seem to be adding +11 minutes to my desired date values when I am converting them using `NSDateFormatter`.

The `startDate` and `endDate` as `NSDate`s on `MyObject`, printed to the console:

START DATE: 2011-11-28 18:00:00 +0000

END DATE: 2011-11-28 20:00:00 +0000

---

My `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:MM a"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

---

Setting the `dateRangeString`:

```
NSString *dateRangeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", 
                                 [formatter stringFromDate:self.startDate],
                                 [formatter stringFromDate:self.endDate]];
```

---

The **wrong** resulting `dateRangeString`:

Date Range: **18:11 PM - 20:11 PM**

Why is it adding an extra 11 minutes to the times?  What am I doing incorrect in my conversion?  Am I forgetting something silly?  SO, please help my sanity!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm a"];
```

`MM` 
is for months.

[Formatting NSDate into particular styles for both year, month, day, and hour, minute, seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936969/nsdate-and-nsdateformatter-short-format-date-and-time-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Yep.  Stupid overlooked mistake, need sleep. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because it's November, the 11th month.

Comment: Noob move, I'm tempted to just delete this. use `mm`

Comment: Easy mistake to make, which is why it was one of the first things I checked.