# I have a one Array its more then thousands of records

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I want to sort array using Year wise and create year wise array and create whole main Array anybody help me?

```
NSArray *anArray = @ @{@"newsID" : @"1",@"userID" : @"3",@"catID" : @"2",@"news" : @"may i know",@"date" : @"Tue, 22 May 2013 00:00:00 GMT+05:30"},];
```

Comment: arrays are not the place to hold this much information, it very much sounds like you need to get yourself a database instead! And whatever that code is supposed to be, its not an array!

Comment: I think he missed @[ from starting of array 
it should be something like this 
NSArray *anArray = @[ @{@"newsID",...

Comment: It would be better if you dumb the data into database , and query the data by date, if you have large amount of data

Comment: First you need to learn the difference between an array and a dictionary!!  And what is the extra "@" there for??

Answer (score 3):

You can use sort descriptors for sorting

```
NSArray *sortedArrayWithDate = [anArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:
                                        ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
                                            NSString  *dt1string = [obj1 objectForKey:@"date"];
                                            NSString *dt2string = [obj2 objectForKey:@"date"];
                                            NSDate *dt1 =[self converttoDate : dt1string];
                                            NSDate *dt2 =[self converttoDate : dt2string];
                                            return [dt1 compare:dt2];

                                        }];
```

you have to create function for converttoDate that takes string as parameter returns date 
you can easily find functions for converting date to string according to date format

References for **stringtodate**

```
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380381/convert-string-to-date-in-my-iphone-app][1]
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936969/nsdate-and-nsdateformatter-short-format-date-and-time-in-iphone-sdk][2]
```

Comment: I think the second date string meant to refer to `obj2`. Also, as a minor refinement, make sure that `convertToDate` doesn't instantiate a new date formatter each time, as that's a relative expensive process. Cache it.

Comment: Except what the OP has is a dictionary.

Comment: @HotLicks - I suspect he really has an array of dictionaries, but omitted the opening `@[`. You'll see the closing `]` at the end. I suspect an editing error in the process of cutting out extraneous portions of his sample to keep it more concise. The title, the text, and the extra `@` make it clear that he intended to specify an array.

Comment: @Rob - It's incredibly common for folks here to attempt to use dictionaries like arrays and vice-versa.

Comment: @HotLicks - Yeah, I know, but IMHO the floating `@` at the start and extra closing `]` make it equally likely that it was a simple editing error. I wouldn't necessarily jump to the conclusion that the OP was oblivious to the difference between dictionaries and arrays.