# NSDate formatting returns null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

when i parse my xml i will get date like this `Fri Nov 06 12:29:39 IST 2015`

This is my xcode part

```
NSLog(@"%@",parsedElementContent);
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
[_currentItem setPubDate:[formatter dateFromString:[self trimString:parsedElementContent]]];
```

Where this part returns null

```
[formatter dateFromString:[self trimString:parsedElementContent]]
- (NSString *)trimString:(NSString *)originalString{
    NSString * trimmedString;
    trimmedString  = [originalString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    return trimmedString;
}
```

I this this part is wrong  **@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"**

Comment: You should use format like : [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd hh:mm:ss 'IST' yyyy"];

Comment: Your dateFormat doesn't match at all the string date your got.

Comment: thank you..i didnt noticed that

Comment: Propose closing as caused  by a simple  error.

Comment: its again showing null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your String indicate is

```
Fri -> EEE (indicate shot day name)
Nov -> MMM (indicate month)
06  -> HH (indicate two digit date)
01  -> mm (indicate two digit month)
00  -> ss (indicate two digit minute)
IST -> IST (indicate current time standerd)
2015-> yyyy (indicate years)
```

so set like

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'IST' yyyy"];
```

And set more NSDate format,  [Click Me](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) and [Click Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936969/nsdate-and-nsdateformatter-short-format-date-and-time-in-iphone-sdk/34355916#34355916)

Comment: Don't forget to add an local, since the date is localized.