# Format "1/31/2016 5:53:21 AM" to "31 Jan'16" in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsdateformatter

I am getting date from json in format "1/31/2016 5:53:21 AM" & i want to convert it to the format "31 Jan'16"...

I tried this code..

```
myDate=@"01/31/2016 05:53:21 AM";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
NSDate *dtNew = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd MMM'YY";
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate]);
```

but `myDate` string can't convert to NSDate. & `dtNew` comes `nil`.

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance.!!!

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSDate and NSDateFormatter - short format date and time in iphone sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936969/nsdate-and-nsdateformatter-short-format-date-and-time-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                          // "1/31/2016 5:53:21 AM" // initial date
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
NSDate *dtNew = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1/31/2016 5:53:21 AM"];
                          // 31 Jan'16 // second date
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd MMM''yy";
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dtNew]);
```

final output is

[image]

Comment: @technerd -- tanx buddy I missed the **'** in dateformat, now I fixed check once

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you should use format ending 'a' and double `'` to escape it.

```
NSString *myDate=@"01/31/2016 05:53:21 AM";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *dtNew = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd MMM''yy";
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dtNew]);
```